# How to add row at the bottom of table in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have select query and I want add row bottom of table which contains sum of debit and credit column.

My SQL query is like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        so.OrderDate ,'Sales' As VoucherType,'' AS VoucherNo,
        a.Total As Debit, NULL As Credit 
    FROM SalesOrder so 
    INNER JOIN
       (SELECT 
           SalesOrderId, SUM(SubTotal) AS Total 
        FROM SalesOrderDetails 
        GROUP BY SalesOrderId) AS a ON so.SalesOrderId = a.SalesOrderId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  
           v.VoucherDate As OrderDate, 'Receipt' AS VoucherType,
           v.VoucherNumber AS VoucherNo, NULL AS Debit,
           v.Amount AS Credit 
        FROM Vouchers v) AS ledger 
ORDER BY 
     OrderDate ASC
```

My query output is in below image.

[image: Here I have attached image of my query result and i want add row end of table. it row contains sum of debit and credit.]

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Comment: i want sum of debit and credit column in last row.so in this query how can i add new row in this table.here i've created ledger.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, why do you want it ? What purpose does it serve ?

Comment: actually bind that data in my application and create report from this table(asp.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `grouping sets`.  First, rearrange the query a bit to be an aggregation query.  The aggregations don't do anything, but they are needed for the total.

Then use `group by grouping sets ()` to define the various groups:

```
SELECT OrderDate, VoucherType, VoucherNo, sum(Debit) as Debit, sum(Credit) as Credit
FROM (SELECT so.OrderDate ,'Sales' As VoucherType, '' AS VoucherNo,
             a.Total As Debit, NULL As Credit
      from SalesOrder so inner join
           (SELECT SalesOrderId,sum(SubTotal) AS Total
            FROM SalesOrderDetails 
            group by SalesOrderId)as a on so.SalesOrderId = a.SalesOrderId
            UNION ALL
            SELECT v.VoucherDate As OrderDate, 'Receipt' AS VoucherType,
                   v.VoucherNumber AS VoucherNo,NULL AS Debit ,
                   v.Amount AS Credit from Vouchers v
           ) ledger
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((OrderDate, VoucherType, VoucherNo), ())
ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
```

Comment: Gordon, is aggregation below a result set an acceptable practice ?

Comment: @blasto . . . I would say so.  Most reasonable databases support some combination of `grouping sets`, `rollup`, or `cube` to allow this functionality.

Comment: Blasto, yes it is; anyone worth their salt in a department needing a report will make a request like this.   

Most, however, will usually argue as to whether it should be done from sql or from your front end in light of the performance discussion.

Comment: I made a table Sums(ID/int, Cash/Int). I don't know if my simplistic query will work here, but it shows me the required output. `SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT ID, cash
FROM Sums
UNION
SELECT 0, SUM(cash)
FROM Sums
) AS S
ORDER BY S.ID DESC`

Comment: this is working. but problem is that sum of column is coming on first row so can you give me a idea how can i set that row at last position.